Await in next js causing infinite loading with no error
I'm trying to query a db with drizzle and show the results but when I await the function querying the db my app starts reloading and never stops until i remove the await. When i remove the await I get a promise and I even tried using .then but the promise won't resolve

"use server"

import { db } from "@/server"

export default async function getPosts(){
  const posts = await db.query.PostsTable.findMany()
  if (!posts){
    return {error: "No posts found"}
  } else {
    return {success: posts}
  }
}

get-posts.ts
import Image from "next/image";
import "dotenv/config"
import getPosts from "@/server/actions/get-posts";


export default async function Home() {
  const data = await getPosts()
  console.log(data) 

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </main>
  );
}

page.tsx
NOTE when i remove the await from infront of the getPosts function call in page.tsx the loop doesn't happen and the following is logged to the console
Promise {
  <pending>,
  [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 11554,
  [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 11531,
  [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: {
    headers: [Getter],
    cookies: [Getter],
    mutableCookies: [Getter],
    draftMode: [Getter],
    reactLoadableManifest: {},
    assetPrefix: ''
  },
  [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: {
    isStaticGeneration: false,
    urlPathname: '/',
    pagePath: '/page',
    incrementalCache: IncrementalCache {
      locks: Map(0) {},
      unlocks: Map(0) {},
      hasCustomCacheHandler: false,
      dev: true,
      disableForTestmode: false,
      minimalMode: false,
      requestHeaders: [Object],
      requestProtocol: 'http',
      allowedRevalidateHeaderKeys: undefined,
      prerenderManifest: [Object],
      fetchCacheKeyPrefix: '',
      cacheHandler: [FileSystemCache]
    },
    isRevalidate: false,
    isPrerendering: undefined,
    fetchCache: undefined,
    isOnDemandRevalidate: false,
    isDraftMode: false,
    prerenderState: null,
    requestEndedState: { ended: false },
    fetchMetrics: []
  },
  [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
  [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
  [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: {
    status: 0,
    flushScheduled: false,
    fatalError: null,
    destination: ReadableByteStreamController {},
    bundlerConfig: {
      '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/Next Apps/test/node_modules/next/font/google/target.css?{"path":"app/layout.tsx","import":"Inter","arguments":[{"subsets":["latin"]}],"variableName":"inter"}': [Object],
      '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/Next Apps/test/app/globals.css': [Object],
      '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/Next Apps/test/node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js': [Object],
      '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/Next Apps/test/node_modules/next/dist/esm/client/components/app-router.js': [Object],
      '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/Next Apps/test/node_modules/next/dist/client/components/client-page.js': [Object],
      '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/Next Apps/test/node_modules/next/dist/esm/client/components/client-page.js': [Object],
      '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/Next Apps/test/node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js': [Object],
      '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/Next Apps/test/node_modules/next/dist/esm/client/components/error-boundary.js': [Object],
      '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/Next Apps/test/node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js': [Object],
      '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/Next Apps/test/node_modules/next/dist/esm/client/components/layout-router.js': [Object],
      '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/Next Apps/test/node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js': [Object],
      '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/Next Apps/test/node_modules/next/dist/esm/client/components/not-found-boundary.js': [Object],
      '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/Next Apps/test/node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js': [Object],
      '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/Next Apps/test/node_modules/next/dist/esm/client/components/render-from-template-context.js': [Object]
    },
    cache: Map(0) {},
    nextChunkId: 6,
    pendingChunks: 6,
    hints: Set(2) {
      'L[font]/_next/static/media/c9a5bc6a7c948fb0-s.p.woff2',
      'L[style]/_next/static/css/app/layout.css?v=1721438843815'
    },
    abortableTasks: Set(3) { [Object], [Object], [Object] },
    pingedTasks: [],
    completedImportChunks: [ [Uint8Array] ],
    completedHintChunks: [],
    completedRegularChunks: [ [Uint8Array], [Uint8Array] ],
    completedErrorChunks: [],
    writtenSymbols: Map(0) {},
    writtenClientReferences: Map(1) {
      '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/Next Apps/test/node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js#' => 3
    },
    writtenServerReferences: Map(0) {},
    writtenObjects: WeakMap { <items unknown> },
    identifierPrefix: '',
    identifierCount: 1,
    taintCleanupQueue: [],
    onError: [Function (anonymous)],
    onPostpone: [Function: eg],
    environmentName: 'Server'
  },
  [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined
}


Hi I've even tried doing this but nothing happens, I'm very confused and don't know what to do at this point

you can change const posts = true; in the query and see if it stops the loop. if it does then it's the db call.

Hi Sean, I did this and learned it is the db call but I know the call returns a promise but when I use await to resolve as mentioned above the loading loop begins

await makes your code wait for a function to finish. It seems your database call never finishes. The Next.js code you provided is okay. Add async back to the database query and review how your server client is set up and called. Add console logs to all your database functions to isolate the problem and identify any repeated calls.
